# Is it possible to control a vector image via a web based color picker?

Tags: javascript

Not sure if I explained this well, but if I were to create a tool that let people customize a birthday invitation and the invitation had vector baloons in the design.  Could I hook up the wizard so they can choose whatever color they wanted?

Comment: What do you mean by `vector balloons`? SVG tooltips? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are using something like [Raphel.js.](http://raphaeljs.com/)

You have this:

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

function makeBallon(raphelObj, stroke, fill)
{
    // Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
    var circle = raphelObj.circle(50, 40, 10);
    // Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
    circle.attr("fill", fill);

    // Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
    circle.attr("stroke", stroke);
}
```

Then

```
makeBallon(paper, '#FF0000', '#454545');
```

Then yes

Comment: Thanks guys! It seems really complicated doing unique illustrations with Raphael. Looking at the code for this tiger illustration makes it seem super tedious.  Example: http://raphaeljs.com/tiger.html    Code: http://d.pr/H2Ce+

Comment: For sure, but it's a dang tiger! It's say a balloon: `var balloon = paper.ellipse(280, 280, 90, 120).attr({fill: "#223fa3", stroke: "#000", "stroke-width": 2, "stroke-opacity": 0.5});
balloon.animate({cy: 0, r: 40}, 2000);`